# How to refer to the whole array within reduce()?

Tags: python, functional-programming

What I have:

```
array = original_array[:]
result = reduce(lambda a,b: some_function(b,array), array)
```

What I want:

I want to get rid of the array = original_array[:] statement.
Ideally I would simply replace the *array* parameter inside *reduce()* with original_array[:], but I need it inside lambda as well. Is there a way to refer to the 
*array* parameter from within lambda?

The following is not an acceptable solution, because it makes a new array copy for every element:

```
result = reduce(lambda a,b: some_function(b,original_array[:]), original_array[:])
```

I need something like this:

```
result = reduce(lambda a,b: some_function(b,reduce_parameter), original_array[:])
```

Comment: What is your `some_function` doing with the array?  Also, why do you want to get rid of `array = original_array[:]`?

Comment: Why? If you need to copy the list, so do so. Do note that I would argue that ``list(original_list)`` is clearer than ``original_list[:]`` for a shallow copy.

Comment: Does your `some_function` modify the list? Because `reduce` doesn't... So you won't need to make a copy in that case.

Comment: As another note, arrays and lists are different things and I really wish people would stop mixing the two terms when it comes to Python.

Comment: some_function() is recursive and this needs to be done in a functional fashion (so no variable assignments)

Comment: Why does ``some_function()`` being recursive matter?

Comment: What happens to parameter `a`?  Are you really doing a reduce?  Perhaps you are trying the wrong algorithm.  What would this look like in a regular old for-loop?

Comment: I made a mistake when I simplified my scenario. some_function() actually uses the *a* parameter as well. Basically I need *reduce* to execute *some_function()* on every element and each of them needs to know the previous result. The whole thing returns the last result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could wrap the whole thing in another lambda:

```
result = (lambda array: reduce(lambda a,b: some_function(b,array), array))(original_array[:])
```

But your original solution is in my opinion preferable because it's more readable.

Comment: +1, and I deleted my answer as I didn't think of this and it's not quite insane, but it is still unreadable, and I agree wholeheartedly with your final comment - you should never do this over the original version.

Comment: @Lattyware I only thought of it because I've abused multiple chained lambdas many times, mostly in the interactive shell when I was too lazy to define a function for a one-time task :)

Comment: It's a clever little way of doing it, I'm far to adverse to lambdas to think it up however. Give me a ``def`` any day of the week.

Comment: +1, because it may not be readable, but it sure is darn cool :)

Comment: `original_array` should be `array` here

Comment: @Eric, read the question again... `array` is a copy of `original_array`, the op wants to get rid of the line copying it.

Comment: @l4mpi: Whoops, you're right. Darn, that means my answer is wrong.

Comment: This does it in one line, but I agree that there is no reason to ever do this.

Comment: Are you sure the second one works? *array* is defined within lambda, but we also need it in reduce() which is outside of lambda.

Comment: @user1132363 you're right of course, I forgot that it is used as the second reduce argument too. I guess the fact that I didn't immediately notice this error shows you how unreadable this is :)

Comment: Also, the first one works well, but you need to put parentheses around the outer lambda. Unless I'm using some weird python version.

Comment: @user1132363 yep, fixed that - I think without parentheses it is interpreted as calling a function on the result of `reduce` instead of calling the outer lambda.

Answer (score 2):

<s>Here's a way to remove that outer lambda</s>

```
result = reduce(lambda a,b,array=array[:]: some_function(b,array), array)
```

*edit: Whoops, misread the question*

This of course assumes you actually need to copy the array, and that it isn't sufficient to use

```
result = reduce(lambda a,b: some_function(b, array), array)
```

Also, this is an incorrect use of reduce - you're not using the `a` argument, so `result` holds `some_function(array[-1], array)`

Comment: nice use of default parameters, I always forget you can use them with lambdas too...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
result = reduce(lambda a,b, array=array: some_function(b,array), array)
```